# Gltf mesh compression on Linux

Tags: linux, gltf

I'm on Arch Linux and Blender 2.91. I want to export a scene in .glb (gltf 2.0) format with mesh compression. According to blender manual, that should be supported via `khr_draco_mesh_compression` extension. A friend of mine who's using Blender 2.91 on Mac has the `compress` option under `geometry` section of the exporter settings but I cannot see such option on Linux.
Any ideas?

Comment: The official build has this option. Please download the official release from the [website](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.91/) and check if the option is still missing. If it is missing, file a bug report on Blender's bug tracker, if it isn't file a bug on Arch's bug tracker as the package maintainer didn't build it properly.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure I did not miss something in my setup.

Comment: Ok I think it's an issue with Arch Linux package as downloading and executing 2.91 from Blender site shows the compress option